# How do I join all values from multiple rows into a single row?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Lets say I have the query:

```
SELECT Foo FROM Bar
```

Which returns

**Foo**
A 
B 
C

What I really what is: 
**Foo**
A,B,C

So all of the values from all of the rows has been collapsed into a single row (the commas are optional).
Is there a way to use a select statement to do this because I do not want to use cursors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    (   
    SELECT
      CASE
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY bar) = 1 THEN ''
        ELSE ', '
      END + CAST(bar AS VARCHAR)
    FROM foo
    ORDER BY bar
    FOR XML PATH('')
    )
```

Comment: This looks "elegant" but quite slow

Comment: Concatenated string do not tend to consist of millions records. For a dozen records which will most probable will there, it will work in a flash.

Comment: In my case, this would only be applied to a few records and it could be used as a subquery in a select statement, which worked best for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @foos VARCHAR(4000)

SELECT @foos = COALESCE(@foos + ',', '') + Foo FROM Bar

SELECT @foos AS Foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Ross,

this should get you started.

```
  DECLARE @r VARCHAR(8000)
  SELECT @r = (SELECT DISTINCT Foo + ', ' FROM Bar FOR XML PATH(''))
  IF @r IS NOT NULL AND @r <> '' SET @r = SUBSTRING(@r, 1, LEN(@r)-1)
  SELECT @r
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
declare @joined varchar(max)
set @joined = ''

select  @joined = @joined + IsNull(Foo + ',', '')
from    Bar (nolock)

--; Drop last "," if necessary
set @joined = substring(@joined, 1, len(@joined) - (case when len(@joined) > 0 then 1 else 0 end))
select  @joined as foo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select max(a),max(b),max(c) from
 (
      select 'a' as a,null as b,null as c
      union
      select null,'b',null
      union
      select null,null,'c'
 ) as x
```